# Send multiple routes to the same destination address

Tags: asp.net-core, ms-yarp

Can I match multiple paths in yarp?

E.g. I have this:

```
endpoints.Map("/place/{**catch-all}", async httpContext =>
{
    var error = await forwarder.SendAsync(httpContext, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/",
        httpClient, requestConfig, transformer);
    // Check if the operation was successful
    if (error != ForwarderError.None)
    {
        var errorFeature = httpContext.GetForwarderErrorFeature();
        var exception = errorFeature.Exception;
    }
});
```

But I would like to do the same for "/geocode/{**catch-all}", without code duplication.

Because the route is just http://localhost/geocode... or http://localhost/place...

So there is nothing before it to match on. I can add something before it instead like http://localhost/proxyme/place/... in my front end, but then in my `CustomTransformer`, `httpContext.Request.Path` has "proxyme/" in it and I don't know how to remove it for use here: `proxyRequest.RequestUri = RequestUtilities.MakeDestinationAddress("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api", httpContext.Request.Path, queryContext.QueryString);` without just doing primitive string operations to delete "proxyme/". So that could be the other option if there is an elegant way to delete "proxyme/" from the `httpContext.Request.Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reuse the same method in the 2 routes:

```
RequestDelegate handler = async httpContext =>
{
    var error = await forwarder.SendAsync(httpContext, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/",
        httpClient, requestConfig, transformer);
    // Check if the operation was successful
    if (error != ForwarderError.None)
    {
        var errorFeature = httpContext.GetForwarderErrorFeature();
        var exception = errorFeature.Exception;
    }
}

endpoints.Map("/place/{**catch-all}", handler);
endpoints.Map("/geocode/{**catch-all}", handler);
```

Answer (score -2):

> I would like to do the same for "/geocode/{**catch-all}", without code
> duplication.

Consider [custom route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-route-constraints):

```
builder.Services.AddRouting(options =>
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("MyConstraint", typeof(MyConstraint)));

 .......
 app.Map("/{my:MyConstraint}/{**catch-all}", () => {.....});





public class MyConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private static readonly string[] AllowedValues = new string[] { "place", "geocode" };

        public bool Match(
            HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey,
            RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var routeValueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (routeValueString is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return AllowedValues.Contains(routeValueString, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

Or define a handler as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lambda-expression)

```
var handler = (HttpContext context) =>
{
   ......
};

app.Map("/Parttern1/{**catch-all}", handler);
app.Map("/Parttern2/{**catch-all}", handler);
```

Comment: You don't need route constraints for this. You can just add multiple routes.